# How to dissable the focus indication in stylesheet

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

When my QDoubleSpinBox is focused, it gets a blue outline to it (in "Fusion" style):

[image]

How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with stylesheets only is *doable*, but has an important drawback: styling complex widgets like a QSpinBox *requires* to correctly set *all* sub control properties.

The basic solution is to set the border for the widget:

```
QSpinBox {
    border: 1px inset palette(mid);
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Keep in mind that offering proper visible response of the focus is *really* important; you might not like the "glow" (and color) the Fusion style offers, but nonetheless it should always be visible when a widget has focus or not, even if it has a blinking text cursor. You can do that by specifying a slightly different color with the `:focus` selector:

```
QSpinBox:focus {
    border: 1px inset palette(dark);
}
```

Unfortunately, as explained in the beginning, this has an important drawback: as soon as the stylesheet is applied, the widget painting falls back to the basic primitive methods (the spinbox on the right uses the stylesheet above):

[image: spinbox difference with stylesheets]

Unfortunately, there's almost no direct way to restore the default painting of the arrows, as using the stylesheet prevents that. So, the only solution is to provide the properties for the controls as explained in the [examples about customizing QSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qspinbox).

There is an alternative, though, using [QProxyStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html). The trick is to intercept the control in the [`drawComplexControl()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html#drawComplexControl) implementation and remove the `State_HasFocus` flag of the option before calling the default implementation.
In the following example, I also checked the focus *before* removing the flag in order to provide sufficient visual feedback, and I also removed the `State_MouseOver` flag which shows the glowing effect when hovering.

```
class Proxy(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawComplexControl(self, cc, opt, qp, widget=None):
        if cc == self.CC_SpinBox:
            opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionSpinBox(opt)
            if opt.state & self.State_HasFocus:
                opt.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, 
                    opt.palette.color(QtGui.QPalette.Window).darker(100))
            else:
                opt.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, 
                    opt.palette.color(QtGui.QPalette.Window).lighter(125))
            opt.state &= ~(self.State_HasFocus | self.State_MouseOver)
        super().drawComplexControl(cc, opt, qp, widget)

# ...
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle(Proxy())
# ...
```

Note that the above "color correction" only works for Fusion style and other styles that use the `Window` palette role for painting the border. For instance, the `Windows` style doesn't consider it at all, or you might want to use higher values of `darker()` or `lighter()` in order to provide better differentiation.

Comment: excellent and informative answer. Thank you very much...don't know if I can give you more credit than just accepting the answer, but it feels like you deserve it.

Comment: @Techniquab You're welcome, and don't worry: accepting (and upvoting) is quite enough :-)